# IOS 7 animation stopped working

Tags: ios, animation

Animation frequently stops working in my APP. It may because I did some UI update in background thread and I found someone provide some classes to swizzles some UIKit methods to check if they are called on the main thread.

The linke is as follows:
https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTFoundation/blob/develop/Core/Source/iOS/Debug/UIView%2BDTDebug.m

The problem is I have no idea how to use it. Anyone used it before? Thank you.

Comment: Instead of adding some third-party thingy, how about thinking about what you're doing wrong in your own code?

Comment: I was trying to check where I updated UI in background thread and I fixed some. Now the problem is not happening that frequently but still can happen. It is so hard to find out the remaining wrong code as the problem happens so random.

Comment: It does sound like a threading problem. But the debugger is excellent on this sort of thing. Simply using NSLog will tell you what thread you are in. More generally, you probably need to rationalize your use of threads; don't get in over your head with background threads, as they are very hard to debug under the best of circumstances.

Comment: Although this doesn't help with using the swizzling code, this is a good workaround (from the App developer forums) to get animations to work again:  
`[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES]`